# Get products from a specific brand in WooCommerce using a WP_Query

Tags: php, woocommerce, product

In WooCommerce, I am trying to display products from a specific brand in my home page like featured products section. I tried the code below, but the products not belong to that brand.

This is what I tried:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',                              
    'product_brand' => 'armitage',
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: No plugins are using to enable brand.it is added as an attribute.

Comment: For brand attribute slug is brand-attr and name is Brand Attr

Comment: For brand name is Armitage and slug is armitage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use tax_query

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'tax_query'      => array( array(
        'taxonomy'        => 'pa_brand-attr',
        'field'           => 'slug',
        'terms'           =>  'armitage',
        'operator'        => 'IN',
    ) )
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: not working field should be always slug right?

Comment: I've edited my answer - attribute taxonomies are prefixed with 'pa_'